# Multiple conditional clauses in a single turn

Tags: clauses

A boy did mischief (he messed with a dog) due to which the following things happened:

1. The dog chased him.
2. Feared, he ran away.
3. He crossed the road.
4. He ran into a car.
5. He had an accident.
6. He is in the hospital now.

Now, his friend is saying to him:

**If you hadn’t messed with the dog, it wouldn’t have chased you and you wouldn’t have run into a car either, neither would you have had an accident nor were you hospitalized.**

Is this correct construction?

Comment: Feared is not a word.  2 should probably read, 2. He became afraid so he ran away.

Comment: @ Msfolly i meant 'frightened'.

Comment: @AlexRaw _Unless_ is not appropriate here; _If you hadn't_ is fine. I would suggest _...had an accident and ended up in hospital_. Didn't you read the first two comments about _feared_?

Comment: @KateBunting I did. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @KateBunting OK - here is the final reduction: *If you hadn't messed with the dog, it wouldn't have chased you, and neither would you have run into a car, had an accident **nor ended up in hospital/nor been hospitalized**.*

Comment: @KateBunting Wonderful!